# variant of Haar measure

Tags: rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

I found a certain trig identity in a discussion on Lie groups

\[ \frac{\prod_{i < j} 2 \sin (\mu_i - \mu_j) 
\prod_{i< j} 2 \sin (\nu_i - \nu_j) }{\prod_{i, j} 2 \cos (\mu_i - \nu_j) } 
 = \det_{i,j} \frac{1}{2 \cos (\mu_i - \nu_j)} \]

This is the [Cauchy determinant formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix).

\[ \det_{i,j} \frac{1}{\mu_i - \nu_j} =  \frac{\prod_{i < j}  \mu_i - \mu_j
\prod_{i< j} \nu_i - \nu_j}{\prod_{i, j}  \mu_i - \nu_j }   \]

It seems to be related to the Haar measure on $U(n)$, which would have a factor:

\[ \prod_{i < j}  \sin (\mu_i - \mu_j)  \]

I am thrown off by the cosine factor in the denominator.

---

Could it be the Haar measure of a quotient on $U(n) \times U(n)$?